# Issue posting parameter in MVC API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a Web API on a site.  If the api call does not have a parameter in it, then I can hit it, but if it has a parameter on it, then I cannot hit it.  Below is an example of what I am talking about.

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetFacilityName2()
{
    return "Good";
}

[HttpGet]
public string GetFacilityName(string projectNumber)
{
    return "Never Get Here";
}
```

My config route is the default at this time.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I am using the following two urls.  Url for the one that works is http://localhost/api/Controller/GetFacilityName2

Url for the one that does not work is http://localhost/api/Controller/GetFacilityName?projectNumber=44

UPDATE
I had a third method on the API that was this.

```
[HttpGet]
public Address GetWorkplaceAddress(string projectNumber)
{
     return new Address();
}
```

When I removed this from the API, the other method started to work. Address is defined as such.

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressValue { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int? State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public int? Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You cannot overload an action on a controller by parameter. You can specify which action you want to occur by name using the RouteAttribute OR you can specify it by the Http verb (Get,Post,Put,etc).

Comment: Each action on the controller has a distinct name on it.  The difference in the one above would be the character '2' at the end.

Comment: That does not matter because your route template ignores the name completely (ie. there is no {action}) and there are no RouteAttributes and without those it will key off of the http verb used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot overload an action on a controller by parameter which is how your code is currently written.

You can specify which action you want to occur by name using

- the `RouteAttribute`
- the route template `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",`

**OR** you can specify it by the Http verb (Get,Post,Put,etc) which is what is currently being done.

Comment: This worked.  I looked over that completely.  Thanks

Comment: @Nate - Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting it as the answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)) once the 15 minutes period has expired.

Comment: I still got 3 min before the system will allow me to accept it as the answer.